# Not able to redirect to the stripe checkout page NextJS

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, sanity

My app does not redirect the user to the stripe checkout page. Used Nextjs to create the app here's a link to the github repo:[ecommerce_repo](https://github.com/sPreet247/ecommerce)

Error: IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.[image: Error]

Comment: Can you try to add `await` for `stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: data.id });`? Please also ensure `data.id` is something like `cs_test_xxx` or `cs_live_xxx`?

Comment: I have tried using await but it does not work, gives out the same error as before

Comment: Is your `data.id` in the correct format, i.e. `cs_test_xxx` or `cs_live_xxx`? Alternatively, you can redirect using [url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url) directly instead of using `stripe.redirectToCheckout(..)`. For example, `window.location={CHECKOUT_URL}` where the checkout URL looks something like `https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_test_xxx`).

Comment: I tried it and it does redirect me to the page but does not show any data.The page is blank.

Comment: Its working now. I forgot to the .id with cs_test_xxx(cs_test_xxx.id). Thanks for the help.